# MvvmCross Rio Binding in Windows 8.1

Tags: binding, xamarin, mvvmcross, windows-8.1

I'm making a project using Xamarin + MvvmCross and I've encountered a problem while trying to make rio binding working on Windows 8.1 Store View app.
I've added references to BindingEx for Windows plugin, FieldBinding plugin and ofc to Hot-Tuna Starter Pack. Unfortunately, every time I'm trying to run my app I'm getting the error:

> "Failed to assign to property 'mvx.Bi.nd'. [Line: 15 Position: 38]"
>   (Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException)

Firsty, I thought that there must be something wrong with my core, so I've created a new project (core & Store UI) but it's all the same... But in WP8 UI project similar approach works like a charm..

Im getting the error using for example this piece of code:

In my core:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.FieldBinding;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

namespace App1.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class FirstViewModel 
        : MvxViewModel
    {
        public INC<string> Sample = new NC<string>("Hi There!");
    }
}
```

In my Store UI:

```
<views:MvxStorePage
    x:Class="App1.Store.Views.FirstView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mvx="using:mvx"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:views="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="55" mvx:Bi.nd="Text Sample" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxStorePage>
```

Comment: To use Bi.nd, have you added the bindingEx initialization to Setup? There's a video showing this in N=35 http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/ - with Setup code - https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-35-Tibet/BindMe.Store/Setup.cs - this is also introduced in "BindingEx - Tibet and Rio in Xaml" in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding

Comment: Yeah of course, it's now working... Such a silly mistake. 
Thanks a lot Stuart.